# large number of Property which depend on other properties

Tags: c#, design-patterns, properties, dependency-properties

We have a class with around 50~60 properties which are dependent on properties on the same class + properties of some other class. Currently on change of one property we are raising the property change of 20 other properties, which make the code messy and error prone. What is the best way to deal with this kind of scenario? Any suggested design pattern to solve this issue?

```
public class ClassA 
{
    public ClassB classB;

    public int Prop1
    {
        get { return CalculateValueForProp1(); }
    }

    private int prop2;
    public int Prop2
    {
        get { return prop2; }
        set
        {
            prop2 = value;
            OnPropertyChange(nameof(Prop2));
            OnPropertyChange(nameof(Prop1));
        }
    }


    private int prop3;
    public int Prop3
    {
        get { return prop3; }
        set
        {
            prop3 = value;
            OnPropertyChange(nameof(Prop3));
            OnPropertyChange(nameof(Prop1));
        }
    }

    public int CalculateValueForProp1()
    {
        return (this.prop2 * 10 + this.Prop1 * 20 + classB.AnotherProperty*10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Break it up to many smaller classes with less responsibility

Comment: 50~60 Properties in any class is simply too much code in one class. It is fundamentals like seperation of concerns that you do not bloat a class like that. So the solution has nothing to do with properties, and will basics.

Comment: You can rise [`INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event with `""` as property name, this will invalidate *all* properties with just *one* event. The best would be to actually do [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) of what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Try to map the dependencies of the properties to a object structure. Therefore you have to find dependencies between the properties.

If you manage to have a base class defining the "basic" properties you can derive classes that bear depending (e.g. calculated) properties. Thus if a base property is changed the derived class should also consume this event, update its properties and fire its own event.

Untested, but I hope you get the point:

```
public class ClassA 
{
    private int prop2;
    public int Prop2
    {
        get { return prop2; }
        set
        {
            prop2 = value;
            OnPropertyChange(nameof(Prop2));
        }
    }

    private int prop3;
    public int Prop3
    {
        get { return prop3; }
        set
        {
            prop3 = value;
            OnPropertyChange(nameof(Prop3));
        }
    }
}

public ClassB classB
{
    public ClassB(ClassA classAinstance)
    {
        classAinstance.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => OnPropertyChange(nameof(Prop1));
    }

    public int Prop1
    {
        get { return (this.prop2 * 10 + this.Prop1 * 20 + classB.AnotherProperty*10); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the sample code, probably that will help.